# How to avoid activating MathJax when I want to use `$` for US currency

Tags: support

The `$` symbol encloses tex commands and acts as a signal for MathJax to engage. What if I want to use `$` for it's other purpose, denoting US currency?

For example, on a recent answer: [synthesizable functional groups](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4798/synthesizable-functional-groups/4809#4809), I wanted to be able to quote the prices of the books I mentioned in US dollars as a deterrent to someone thinking they should go out and acquire their own individual copies. Ultimately, I chose to leave the prices out and just insinuate that they were high. I also linked to the Amazon listing.

If I want to quote a single dollar amount, then all is well. If I use `$1000`, then I get the following $1000, which is good.

If I want to quote two dollar amounts in the same paragraph, I get a MathJaxsplosion: `$500 price ... some text [a link](http:\\www.google.com) ... ca. $1000` becomes: $500 price ... some text [a link](http:\\www.google.com) ... ca. $1000

Interesting, but undesirable. Is there a way around this behavior without using `$`, since the preformatted block carries other connotations on the stackexchange sites? Is there a snippet of MathJax code I can insert around a chunk of text to ingore while rendering?

```
$\DoNotRenderThisTextWithMathJaxIWantItToLookLikeUnrenderedText{the text I want to looking normal with $500 and some $1000 in it}$
```

Or is there some way I can drop in a unicode character that looks like `$`, but won't trigger MathJax?

Comment: "MathJaxsplosion" made me laugh

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you pay me \$100 I would tell you, give me \$200 and I'll throw in some fries on the side :)

(If you've done some programming, the solution is obvious, but that's not always the case)

Comment: For those who can't click the edit button: [see the source code](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/revisions/d5701895-ed87-48fa-92e6-4717f3b95502/view-source)

Comment: Don't listen to Manish, I'll tell you for $50!

Comment: Thanks! It makes so much sense, I can't believe I did not try it.